# Converting a BufferedImage to another type

Tags: java, image-processing

The most convenient method to read an image from a source (`File`s, `InputStream`s, `URL`s)  is:

```
BufferedImage myImage = ImageIO.read( source );
```

But then, **how to convert `myImage` to a `BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_565_RGB` format?**

Comment: `@user172825` **Welcome to StackOverflow!** I recommend you to change your username.

Comment: This is very helpful! +1

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can create a new BufferedImage of the required type and then draw the original image on it, something like:

```
    BufferedImage bufImg = ImageIO.read( imageURL );
    BufferedImage convertedImg = new BufferedImage(bufImg.getWidth(), bufImg.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_565_RGB);
    convertedImg.getGraphics().drawImage(bufImg, 0, 0, null);
```

Comment: This is an old question, but once should not forget to use ```dispose()``` after using drawImage().

Comment: I know this is a common method, but it is also super slow. Is there anything faster?