# Java - BufferedImage and changing a model

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, pixel, raster

I do have two BufferedImage objects. 
The first one has the following parameters:

> BufferedImage@3fb397fb: type = 5 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 24
>   numComponents = 3 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@64594484
>   transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false
>   ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 250 height = 250 #numDataElements 3
>   dataOff[0] = 2

The second one has:

> BufferedImage@22ee5f73: type = 6 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 32
>   numComponents = 4 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@64594484
>   transparency = 3 has alpha = true isAlphaPre = false
>   ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 250 height = 250 #numDataElements 4
>   dataOff[0] = 3

How can I make them compatible if they are two different picture?

Comment: What have you tried so far to make them compatible? How did it work out (or not)?

Comment: Where do these BufferedImages come from (eg. from a file etc.)?

Comment: The one image comes from a file and the second one is from camera. I am converting those into a matrix and because of numComponents = 4, the first one has 187500 length, and the second one has 250000.

Comment: The BufferedType, which is labeled as "type = 6" was originally saved as a bitmap "Bitmap.Config ARGB_8888". I need to convert loaded images to the similar format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a BufferedImage to another type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194080/converting-a-bufferedimage-to-another-type)