# TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED equivalent in PDFBox 2.0.x

Tags: pdfbox

I am trying to migrate from PDFBox 1.8.8 to 2.0.1 but what is the equivalent to use for `TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED` in PDFBox 2.0.x ?

Comment: It was removed in 2014 due to poor performance, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1963 07/Mar/14 14:02 . The solution would be to render to RGB and then convert to whatever unsupported type you want.

Comment: @Tilman that comment qualifies as an answer.

Comment: @mkl ok, done. Initially at that time, TYPE_BINARY was removed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering to TYPE_INDEXED was removed in 2014 due to alleged poor performance, see [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1963?focusedCommentId=13923863&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13923863).

> ...because it prevents the user from passing in arbitrary types which are
>   known to cause poor performance e.g. TYPE_INT_BGR, well actually any
>   type other than TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, TYPE_BYTE_GRAY, TYPE_INT_RGB or
>   TYPE_INT_ARGB.

The solution would be to render to RGB and then [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194080/converting-a-bufferedimage-to-another-type) to whatever unsupported type you want.